# To get image from cifat10-dataset

Tags: python, image, dataset

I am trying to get images from cifar10-dataset. When i rebuild image from array,
i see 9 same images in one picture, i don't know what is the problem.

When i load image from data, `single_img` shape (3072,). After that, i reshape
my `single_img` varible  (32, 32, 3). I don't know where is the problem.
Here my code;

```
import cPickle
from  PIL import Image
import numpy as np

f = open("/home/leo/Downloads/cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1", "rb")

tupled_data= cPickle.load(f)

f.close()

img = tupled_data['data']

single_img = np.array(img[0])

single_img_reshaped = single_img.reshape(32, 32 ,3)

j = Image.fromarray(single_img_reshaped)

j.save("/home/leo/Desktop/blabla.bmp")
```

Example image;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to be careful about the format of the pixel array of the image..

```
[R....G....B]
```

So you just change its format to

```
[[[R,G,B],....,[R,G,B]]
[[R,G,B],....,[R,G,B]]
[[R,G,B],....,[R,G,B]]]
```

But

`single_img_reshaped = single_img.reshape(32, 32 ,3)`

don't do it like before.